# Azure Backup Cannot Modify Policy - Missing Drive Letters

Tags: backup, azure

We've recently done some drive swapping on our server. As a result, several drive letters and paths no longer exist.

Azure Backup Agent won't let me modify my policy. The policy contains some of those that have been removed, and consequently I am seeking to remove them from the policy.

However, attempting to do so by going through the "Schedule Backup" wizard, the only way I can identify to modify the policy, gives me an error because the path is invalid. It can't be found. But that's the point, it's not there anymore. How can I circumvent or solve this and successfully update my Azure backup policy in the Azure Backup Agent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new policy and then applying that one, instead of modifying an existing one?